# Cocos2d Bow-Arrow movement with air friction and no physics engine, How?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

I've spent the last 2 days figuring out the movement of an arrow shot from a bow with no perfect end result. Here is what I have so far:

```
    - (void) update:(ccTime) dt {
    elapsedTime += dt;
    CGFloat t = elapsedTime;
    float theta = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle);
    velocity = ccp (initialVelocity.x* cos(theta), initialVelocity.y*sin(theta));


    float k = 0.3; //this would be the air resistance factor
    float vvx = sqrtf( velocity.x*velocity.x + velocity.y*velocity.y );
    float vvy = sqrtf( velocity.x*velocity.x + velocity.y*velocity.y );

    CGFloat ax = -k*vvx; //accelerationX
    CGFloat ay = -k*vvy - gravity; //accelerationY


    velocity = ccp(velocity.x + ax * t , velocity.y + ay * t);

    CGPoint oldPosition = self.position;
    CGPoint newPosition = ccp(self.position.x + velocity.x * t + ax * t * t, self.position.y + velocity.y * t + ay * t * t);

    CGPoint v1 = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    CGPoint v2 = CGPointMake(newPosition.x - oldPosition.x ,  newPosition.y - oldPosition.y);
   CGFloat newAngle = (atan2(v2.y, v2.x) - atan2(v1.y, v1.x));
    self.rotation = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(-newAngle);
    self.position = newPosition;

}
```

Using this code I get this behaviour:

Using: k = 0.3 and angle = 0 degrees, gravity = 9.8

With initialVelocity = 100 the arrow has a nice parabola trajectory

With initialVelocity = 200 the arrow moves faster but has the exact same trajectory as with initialVelocity = 100

With initialVelocity = 300 the arrow moves a lot faster and the trajectory is slightly different but still very close to the trajectory of initialVelocity = 100

Is something wrong with my code? Please note that I don't have a very good understanding of all the notions, much of the implementation is a hit & miss based on what I've read online.

Comment: do you really need to implement it by yourself? you've already spent two days, but you can achieve this by spending few hours to add physical engine to your project.

Comment: well since it shouldn't be a very difficult task for a person who knows what he is doing I don't think I should rely on a physics engine just for that.

Comment: ok. in such a way, dont use frameworks at all, and write your program with assembler, without using objective-c.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of your responses. Obviously you have no clue about the problem but still respond. Any reason why?

Comment: I agree with Horatiu, this is pretty simple I'm sure and implementing a big, bloated physics engine would be way overkill. Going by what Morion is saying, might as well just skip the whole game development process and buy video games from Game Stop! It's much simpler than making your own! /sarcasm. On topic, for the rotation, you could calculate where the arrow would land and then add 90degrees to the arrow's rotation over the time it would take for the arrow to collide with the ground, or anything else for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding in acceleration multiple times.  You have:

```
velocity = ccp(velocity.x + ax * t , velocity.y + ay * t);
```

and then below that:

```
CGPoint newPosition = ccp(self.position.x + velocity.x * t + ax * t * t, self.position.y + velocity.y * t + ay * t * t);
```

It looks to me like you could simplify that second line to just

```
CGPoint newPosition = ccp(self.position.x + velocity.x * t, self.position.y + velocity.y * t);
```

However, I think your overall algorithm is more complicated than it needs to be, and that makes bugs harder to find.  There shouldn't be any reason to track angle; just separate the vectors and handle each independently.  In pseudocode, something like this:

```
// setup
vx = cos(InitAngle) * InitVelocity;
vy = sin(InitAngle) * InitVelocity;
locx = 0;
locy = 0;
gravity = -1.0;
friction  -0.01;

// loop
Update(t) {
  vx *= 1+(friction * t);
  vy +=gravity * t;
  locx += vx * t;
  locy += vy * t;
}
```

(I may have the sin/cos reversed; I always get that wrong.)

Comment: To add to that:  If you need the angle of the arrow, compute it separately by doing an arctan of vx and vy... but don't make it part of your actual movement calculation.  Also, I changed your friction calculation to make it multiplicative instead of additive; it's more realistic that way.  Otherwise, friction could result in accelerating backwards movement.  Also... I didn't apply friction to the Y component, but it probably should be added, by multiplying it after gravitational acceleration is added in.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. The movement is right now using your advice. However when I add the friction on the vy component my arrow goes up when it should be going down. What I do is this vy += gravity * t * friction. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Horatiu, if you don't want to use a physical engine and you want to go via hit&miss, I would suggest to begin without air resistance. Begin simple, gather help from easy physics: the equation of a thrown object (acceleration, speed, position, derivation and time) and then when it's fine, add the air friction.
When you'll have the correct equations, coding will be an easy step!